# Как посчитать прирост или спад процентах?

Tags: php, математика

Как посчитать прирост или спад в процентах при условии, что одно из чисел может быть равно "0" и процентное соотношение может быть выше 100% ?

Например: 
старое число 1, новое число 586. 
Соответственно прирост будет составлять 586%.
А если старое число 400, а новое 0 - спад составит 400% и т.п

Comment: (new-old)/old*100 а если старое 0 - то результат бессмысленный

Comment: `А если старое число 400, а новое 0 - спад составит 400% ` то спад составит 100% .

Comment: Вы прямо как тот бизнесмен из анекдота: "За сто покупаю, за триста продаю, и вот эти вот три процента разницы - моя прибыль"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то обычно за 100% берется старое значение. Итак,

```
изменение = (новое_значение - старое_значение)/старое_значение * 100%
```

Так что для *старое число 1, новое число 586* рост составляет 58500%, а для *старое число 400, а новое 0* - спад составит 100%.

P.S. См. учебник по математике для начальной школы.

P.P.S. И да - если сначала нечто вырастет на 20%, а потом на 20% уменьшится - оно не будет равно тому, что было изначально...

Comment: Огромная просьба к тому, кто считает эту формулу неверной - а иначе откуда минус? - привести свою...

Comment: Видимо, школьники